# How to assign height of table row in CSS and place every row under the other starting from top?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables, row-height

```css
.block {
  width: 445px;
  height: 544px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(24, 24, 28, 0.45);
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 3px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.row {
  height: calc(100% / 7);
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <table class="table">
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell">A</td>
      <td class="cell">B</td>
      <td class="cell">C</td>
      <td class="cell">D</td>
      <td class="cell">E</td>
      <td class="cell">F</td>
      <td class="cell">G</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell">1</td>
      <td class="cell">2</td>
      <td class="cell">3</td>
      <td class="cell">4</td>
      <td class="cell">5</td>
      <td class="cell">6</td>
      <td class="cell">7</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image]

I have a problem with height of the row element - I want it to be height of table (100%) divided by 7 (and I have calc(100% / 7)), but it doesn't work. As you see on the screen - it is 267px and should be much less. I want this rows to start on the top of the table with normal height (so there should be two rows, one under the other and a lot of blank space underneath, because the table have 100% height of block element). I am creating rows dynamically and they will fill all the table (so I will have 7 rows which will have the same height and which will fill all the table). Where I made a mistake? Thanks for your help!

Desired output with two rows:
[image]

Desired output with seven rows:
[image]

Comment: I feel like a screenshot of the final desired output would help with your description.

Comment: I believe table rows will always fill out the table even if you explicitly set the height. Since the table is height 100% of its parent (544px) and it only has 2 rows each row will be 50% or 272px

Answer (score -1):

You just need to define a `display` property on the row for the `height` to take effect.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/dieguezz/q2j6me6h/

```
.row {
  height: calc(100% / 7);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. ;)

Comment: Anyway, instead of using that ugly `calc` you might consider using flexbox to distribute the height proportionally